# Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed.?8

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I have to send mail using my web application. Given below code showing one error. The error is :

> Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed.

Help me to find a proper solution. Thank you.

**Code:**

```
protected void btnsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Ticket_MailTableAdapters.tbl_TicketTableAdapter tc;
    tc = new Ticket_MailTableAdapters.tbl_TicketTableAdapter();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = tc.GetEmail(dpl_cate.SelectedValue);
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        string eml = (row["Emp_Email"].ToString());
        var fromAddress = "emailAddress";
        var toAddress = eml;
        const string fromPassword = "*****";
        string body = "Welcome..";
        // smtp settings
        var smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
               {
                 smtp.Host = "outlook.office365.com";
                 smtp.Port = 993;
                 smtp.EnableSsl = true;

                 smtp.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                 smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress, fromPassword);
                 smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                 smtp.Timeout = 600000;
               }
        // Passing values to smtp object
         smtp.Send(fromAddress, toAddress, subject, body);
     }
}
```

**Error:**

[image]

Comment: try `smtp.Host = smtp.office365.com`, `smtp.Port = 587` `smtp.EnableSsl = true;`

Comment: @Banana : I have changed my code  as per your suggestion, but it is showing new error. The error is: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM

Comment: verify the fromAddress and the password, you might have a typing error in your orignal code.

Answer (score 0):

Try commenting `smtp.EnableSsl = true;` and run it again and see if it works.

In some cases, if you are using `smtp` host with domain name you don't need secure connection.Also check on the port that you are using here and increase you timeout limit just for the sake of having a larger gap.

Comment: I commented the smtp.EnableSsl, but showing the same error.

Comment: @Reshma commenting out the ssl is not enough. you need to change the port accordingly.

Comment: @Banana : which port I have to use.?

Answer (score 0):

Put this in the beginning

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```